# Finding the minimum number of moves changing integers to match others in a list

Tags: python, loops

I am extremely new to coding, and as part of an application to a bootcamp was presented with a problem I have been working on all day but Im stumped. It is also timed and I only have about 12 hours left. I must take two integers and match them to a second pair of integers by moving each digit up or down, then adding the minimum number of moves it took me to do so, which would be the final answer. This is my first time using any kind of proramming languge past CSS, so please bear with me. The eample is as follows:

"Andrea and Maria each have an array of integers. Andrea wants to change her array to match Maria's. For each element of her array, sha can increment or decrement on digit in one item in one move. How many moves will it take Andrea to match Marias array.

Complete the function minimumMoves

minimumMoves has the following paramaeters:
a[a[0],...a[n-1]]:
m[m[0],...m[n-1]]:

Im so lost and I really need someone to point me in the right direction. Please Help!!!

Ive googled and googled but I just cant wrap my head around it, how to pick out each digit from the integer and go through each one without writing a new line of code for every digit.

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys



#
# Complete the 'minimumMoves' function below.
#
# The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
# The function accepts following parameters:
#  1. INTEGER_ARRAY a
#  2. INTEGER_ARRAY m
#

def minimumMoves(a, m):
    # Write your code here
    a = [4321, 3211]
    m = [5432, 4302]
    total=0
        if a[0] <= b[0]
           a[0] += 1
        else if a[0] >= b[0]
            a[0] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

[zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) two times the stringified integers to compare digit by digit and sum absolute differences.
It's not clear to me if 9 -> 1 would be two moves (9 -> 0 -> 1) or eight. I assume the latter:

```
def minimumMoves(a, m):
    a = [str(x) for x in a]
    m = [str(x) for x in m]
    return sum([
        abs(int(f) - int(s)) 
        for x, y in zip(a, m) 
        for f, s in zip(x, y)
    ])

a = [4321, 3211]
m = [5432, 4302]

minimumMoves(a, m)

>>> 8
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean same index digit in list, you can try this:

```
def minimumMoves(a, m):
    # Write your code here
    a = [4321, 3211]
    m = [5432, 4302]
    total = 0
    # iterate the array of a and m together
    for i, j in zip(a, m):
        # means how many steps to turn i into j
        total += abs(i - j)
    return total
```

Hope that will help you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Comment: Thank you, but Basically i need to increment or decrement each digit to turn Andreas numbers into marys, and then add up how many moves it took. ie: the first digit must go up 1 time, the second digit up one time the 3rd digit up one time and the fourth digit up one time, for a total of 4 moves, then the same for the second number, which would be 3 moves, then the sum of those two numbers being the output of 7

Comment: sorry for my misunderstanding, I am still confused about your requirement, for second number, 3211->4302, also change 4 times, 1th, 2th, 4th go up, 3th go down.

Comment: and second question is, when 1->4, it cost 3 moves or 1 moves?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [4321, 3211]
m = [5432, 4302]
s=0
n=[]
l=[]



for i in range(len(a)):
    [n.append(int(d)) for d in str(a[i])]
    [l.append(int(d)) for d in str(m[i])]
    for j in range(len(n)):
        s=s+abs(n[j]-l[j])
    n.clear()
    l.clear()

print(s)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
def minimumMoves(a, m):
    total = 0
    for i, j in zip(a, m):
       n1= str(i)
       n2 = str(j)

       if len(n1) == len(n2):
           for dig in range(len(n1)):
               total += abs(int(n1[dig]) - int(n2[dig]))

    print(total)

a = [123,543]
m = [321,279]

minimumMoves(a,m)
```

This will help you achieve what you want. But this will only be possible if number of digits at the same index in both arrays are same. I wasn't sure if testcases other than this will be present or not.